# why do C compilers make a distinction between ints and pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I've been reading a lot of questions and answers on here about C pointers, but haven't found anything explaining why C doesn't allow addresses to be stored in regular ints-- it seems to be to be simpler to type:

```
int a = 100;
int b = &a;
int c = &b;    //etc
```

rather than

```
int a = 100;
int* b = &a;
int** c = &b;    //etc
```

Actually, I'm not sure if all compilers disallow this, or if it just flags a warning.  But If I'm getting the same thing accomplished, (storing the address of a variable for reference), what difference does it make if I use pointer notation or just assign the values directly?

Comment: For one thing, pointer operations, e.g. incrementation, are done depending on the `sizeof()` of the pointer type. If you hold the address in an `int` it will only increment by 1.

Comment: You *can* store the address of something in a normal `int` (if the address fits in an `int`), but how would you dereference the pointer then?

Comment: because an `int`, is an `int` and is treated as such.

Comment: Why should you expect a pointer value fit inside an `int` in the general case, anyway?

Comment: a pointer to an int is a very different type from a simple int. the reason why no compilers should allow you to store a pointer to an int (int*) into an int is because c/c++ is a strongly typed language and those types just aren't compatible. you could play with operator overloading and possibly achieve a result similar to what you want but I don't think that's the point here.

Comment: If you have a pointer to a `double` and store the pointer in an int, how would you safely and conveniently get back the double ? And there are ofcourse platforms where a simple int cannot represent a pointer (Say, on a 64 bit platform which uses 64 bits for pointers and 32 bits for an int)

Comment: this is good information, anyone of these would serve well as an answer, @nos I didn't know 64 bit machines used 32 bit ints, that's really good to know, thanks.

Comment: You're right, all those *types* really just get in the way. Why can't we just operate on raw registers and memory without all those annoyances?

Comment: @KerrekSB I see what you did there...

Comment: It seems to be easier to get rid of the type altogether. But it's not, because humans easily make errors and the compiler can catch that. Besides that, each type may have a different size and representation. As an example, an `int` may be 4-bytes and a pointer be 8-bytes (this is very common actually)

Comment: @Shahbaz: The common mantra always seems to be that types "help prevent errors", but I have always had a hard time understanding that position. Coming from a C++ background, it seems to me that a type system encompasses such a large part of the high-level semantics of my data (ownership, resource management) that it's much more about what I want to happen ("free this memory") than it is about "preventing errors"...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I really wouldn't know the first "inventors" of type-systems thought. In a modern world, that is true. The type system plays a huge role in our programming. But the fact that 45 years ago, C (or even its ancestors) differentiated between `int` and `char` for example probably comes from a more basic need in programming, which I guess is preventing errors. So perhaps "the common mantra" comes from the original reason for the type-system. Or perhaps there is another reason altogether, knowing which would be beyond me without any research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

Because if all addresses were stored only in a common data type, such as `int`, or `void *`, then the only information you'd have would be the address, which is not enough to use the data at that address. In particular, in order to use the data at that address, you also need to know:

1. *How much* data is stored at that address; and
2. *What* that data is intended to represent.

## Long Answer Part 1 - Quantity

As you may know, different data types in C are stored in different amounts of memory. `char` always takes one byte, and it's typical these days for `short` to take two bytes, and `int` to take four bytes, for instance.

The address of a variable is always the address of the *first byte* of the data stored in that variable. If, for instance, you were to define `int var = 0xDEADBEEF;` and the compiler decided to store that variable at memory location 100, then the memory would look like this (on a little-endian system with four byte `int`s):

```
-----------------------------------------
|   100   |   101   |   102   |   103   |
|   0xEF  |   0xBE  |   0xAD  |   0xDE  |
-----------------------------------------
```

If, on the other hand, you were to define `char c = 0x09;` and the compiler were to store that at memory location 200, then it might look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   200   |   201   |   202   |   203   |
|   0x09  | Garbage | Garbage | Garbage |
-----------------------------------------
```

So if this was allowed:

```
int main(void) {
    int var = 0xDEADBEEF;
    char c = 0x09;

    int pv = &var;        /* Not allowed in ISO C */
    int pc = &c;          /* Not allowed in ISO C */

    int sum = my_func(pv, pc);

    ....
}

int my_func(int p1, int p2) {
    int a = *p1;          /* Not allowed in ISO C */
    int b = *p2;          /* Not allowed in ISO C */
    return a + b;
}
```

then how would the compiler know what values to assign to `a` and `b` in `my_func()`? Sure, the compiler knows the address of the data that `p1` points to, but when it wants to dereference that pointer, find out the value of the data, and store the value in `a`, does it take the value at memory location `100`? Or the value at memory locations `100` and `101`? Or the value at memory locations `100`, `101`, `102` and `103`? Or something else?

If you just stored all pointers in one type of variable, the compiler would know where each data element *began* in memory, but it would have no idea *how much* data was at that address.

*If*, on the other hand, you require people to store pointers to `int` in a `int *`, and pointers to `char` in a `char *`, then the compiler *does* know. If you have an `int *` pointer containing the address `100`, and you ask the compiler to deference it, then it knows you want the value stored at address `100` *and the next three bytes*, since the fact it's an `int *` tells the compiler that an `int` is stored there, and an `int` takes four bytes (on this particular hypothetical implementation).

On the other hand, if you store address `100` in a `char *` and ask the compiler to go get the value at address `100`, it knows to *only get the one byte value stored at that single memory address*, and to ignore any following bytes, because it knows a `char` occupies a single byte.

So when you have data types of different sizes, knowing their addresses is not enough. You also need to know how many bytes of memory they occupy, otherwise when you try to retrieve the value, you don't know how many bytes of memory to read. If you use a different pointer type to point to each basic type, then you *do* know how many bytes of memory to read.

## Long Answer Part 2 - Meaning

Consider this (non-portable) program, on a little-endian architecture that uses ASCII:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_string(void * ptr) {
    char * c = ptr;
    printf("String is: %s\n", c);
}

void print_int(void * ptr) {
    int * p = ptr;
    printf("Int is: %d\n", *p);
}

int main(void) {
    char * c = "Ptr";
    int n = 7500880;

    print_string(&n);
    print_string(c);
    print_int(&n);
    print_int(c);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./testmem
String is: Ptr
String is: Ptr
Int is: 7500880
Int is: 7500880
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

It turns out that sometimes strings and `int`s are somehow the same things. How is this so?

In this case, the three-character string `"Ptr"` (four characters, including the terminating null) will be stored as the ASCII character `'P'`, which is `0x50`, followed by the ASCII character `'t'`, which is `0x74`, followed by the ASCII character `'r'`, which is `0x72`, following by the null character, which is `0x00`. If the string began at memory location 100, the four byte would look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   100   |   101   |   102   |   103   |
|   0x50  |   0x74  |   0x72  |   0x00  |
-----------------------------------------
```

The number `7500880`, which is `0x00727450` represented as hexadecimal, will be stored with the bytes in reverse order on a little-endian machine, and storing the four-byte integer `7500880` will *also* be represented by the four bytes:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   200   |   201   |   202   |   203   |
|   0x50  |   0x74  |   0x72  |   0x00  |
-----------------------------------------
```

So those four bytes in memory can be interpreted *either* as the integer `7500880` *or* as the string `"Ptr"` - on this particular machine, the bit pattern to represent both pieces of data are identical. In other words, if I showed you this block of memory in the absence of any context:

```
-----------------------------------------
|   300   |   301   |   302   |   303   |
|   0x50  |   0x74  |   0x72  |   0x00  |
-----------------------------------------
```

and asked you, "did I store the string `"Ptr"` at memory location `300`, or did I store an `int` with the value `750880` at memory location `300`?", *you would not be able to tell me*. For that matter, I could have stored a four byte RGBA value at that location, with a red value of 80, and green value of 116, a blue value of 114, and an alpha value of 0, and you'd be none the wiser.

This is actually a specific observation of a general fact, that *any* information we store on a computer has to be represented as bits and bytes, and that the bits and bytes do not, themselves, have any meaning. This turns out to be true for any encoding whatsoever. For instance, if we stored the string `"Ptr"` in UTF-16 rather than ASCII, then instead of being represented as `0x50747200`, it would be represented as `0x5000740072000000`, but the meaning would be the same.

So, if we are representing information as bits, and we want to have any fighting chance at all of any actual *communication* occurring then we need to be sure that *the receiver knows how to decode the bits in a method consistent with the way we encoded them*. I can sent you the message "SOS" in morse code with `... --- ...`, but if you have a broken morse code table that tells you `...` actually stands for "H", and `---` stands for "A", then the message will be lost forever.

The upshot of all this is that even when you know the *size* of the data stored at a particular address, this is *still* not enough - you also have to know *how* the data is represented.

For example, on my system, both `long` and `double` take up 8 bytes, and the value `0xDEADBEEF` can be represented precisely in both types, but the bit pattern for the `long` will be:

```
0xEFBEADDE00000000
```

and the bit pattern for the `double` will be:

```
0x41EBD5B7DDE00000
```

Same value, completely different representation at the bit level. So again, even if I know the address of the variable, and I know that it takes up 8 bytes, I *still* need to know more information - I need to know the *type* of the data because I cannot make sense of it without knowing *how* the data is represented, and `long` and `double` do not represent the same data in the same way.

So, to go back to the short answer, if you just used `int` to store any and all pointers, or even if you just used a `void *`, you couldn't make any sense of the data you found at those addresses, because you need to know both how much data is there, and how to interpret the bits you find there. When a pointer to an `int` is stored in an `int *`, and a pointer to a `double` is stored in a `double *`, and a pointer to a pointer to a `char` is stored in a `char **`, then you *do* know both of these things, and you can therefore make sense of your data.

Answer (score 5):

The most fundamental reason is of course that when you want to *use*  a pointer, i.e. dereference it to access the value it points at, you *must* know the type of that value.

Otherwise, how would the compiler generate the proper instruction for that particular type?

Consider a pointer to a character vs a pointer to an `int`. In most cases, the latter value is 4, sometimes 8, times larger. Obviously this affects how the value is accessed and processed.

Without differentiating between the pointer types, this becomes impossible.

Comment: of course this is important only for a static typed languages such as c/c++.

Comment: +1. Since all data is just bits to the machine, the address is only half the story. Even in the absence of differing sizes, it's only the difference between `int *` and `char *` that allows the compiler to distinguish between the four-byte integer `0x00727450` (on a little-endian architecture) and the string `"Ptr"`, which are otherwise represented with the exact same 32 bits of memory.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, pointers are just integers so you can treat them as such in many cases. Assembler languages have no pointer type, instead they use "direct" or "indirect" access.

However, there are many CPUs where the address bus and data bus have different sizes. For example, on the average 8-bit micro-controller, you can typically address 65k of memory (16 bits) but only perform computations of 8 bits of data. Also, obscure architectures are allowed by C - in theory pointers need not correspond directly to physical addresses.

So that's the main reason why pointers were invented. But then of course, there are various things in the C language that make pointers more than just a raw number. You can do pointer arithmetic, you can have arrays decaying into pointers, you can get a bit of type safety and const correctness through pointers, and so on.

Also, please note that `int` is a signed type and it most likely doesn't make any sense for a system to have negative addresses.

This is what the C standard 6.3.2.3 says regarding conversions:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

In other words, conversions between pointers and integers are system-specific. And if you do something that doesn't make sense (for example storing a pointer value inside a signed `int`, as in your example), then you are on your own and neither the compiler nor the language makes any guarantees of what will happen.

Comment: thanks for this-- I noticed most books or tutorials on C talk about the "how" and never so much the "why", which I think is just as important, to avoid making these kinds of errors in judgment.

Answer (score 0):

**What is pointers??**

Pointer is a varible which is used to store the memory location of another variable.

**How to declare pointers?**

```
int *a;
int* a;
int*a;      // all gives the same meaning
```

**Why we need pointers?**

Pointers is a effective way of programming since the programmer is able to acces the memory location where  the variable is stored (best explained using a swapping function).

**So!!!!**

Simply doing

```
int b = &a;
```

**doesn't** impies that **b** is a pointer ,it's just a variable which stores address of another variable and the value at **a** can't be accessed using **b**.

whereas

```
int* b = &a;
```

implies **b** is a pointer and holds the memory location of variable **a**,so de-referencing the pointer will give the value of variable **a**

Comment: A pointer is not a variable; a pointer is a *value* that *refers to a variable*.

Comment: @ Eric Lippert , I don't know why you said that (A pointer is not a variable;) . Acoording to Dennis Ritchie & Brian w. Kernighan "A POINTER IS A VARIABLE THAT CONTAINS ADDRESS OF A VARIABLE".

Comment: No way, K&R actually *says* that?  That's crazy!  Suppose we have `int x[2]; int *a = &x[0]; int *b = ((a + 1) - 1);` So clearly `a` and `b` are variables. But `((a+1)-1)` is clearly a pointer -- we assign it to `b`, so it must be. But K&R is telling us that `((a+1)-1)` is a *variable*?  I don't buy it.

Comment: @EricLippert Looks like it's true; pointers are consistently referred to as "variables" throughout K&R. (e.g. "... since pointers are variables, they can be used without dereferencing. For example, if `iq` is another pointer to `int`, `iq = ip` copies the contents of `ip` into `iq`, thus making `iq` point to whatever `ip` pointed to.") It does seem to conflate the type of a variable with the variable itself.

Comment: @dlev: I have been wondering for some time why it is that C programmers seem so fixed on this strange idea that pointers are variables; this goes a long way to explaining that.

Comment: Precision can get in the way of communication, sometimes. It seems not unreasonable, when you have `int n; int * p;` to refer to both `n` and `p` colloquially as "variables", and then to go further and state that "`n` is an `int` and `p` is a pointer (to `int`)". Other than in relation to condition variables, I can only find one reference in the standard to the colloquial usage of the term outside of the footnotes, in Section 7.17.2.1.3, where it seems synonymous with "object". Appendix F does mention "`float_t` and `double_t` variables" in a footnote, conflating variables and their types.

Answer (score -2):

long past ago C use int and int* interchangable

but on time K&R they try more type security.

u can see Lions commentary where use

int -> somefild

and where struct { int a}

so u can get typecasting for any pointer pointer->a and u get int interpretation of *pointer value

and it that time u not need union and (type) cose struct get it to u